# Why there are two sdcards location in my emulator?

Tags: android, sd-card

My Android version is 4.4, and i created a emulator with the 50 MB Size

After start the emulator and i run the adb shell command.
Found ther is a sdcard dir below the /whic permission is lrwxrwxrwx

But there is another sdcard dir below the /storage/ which permission is drwxrwx--x, are those two dirs are the same one?If so, why those two dirs have different permission?

whic sdcard path will be return when i run the below sentence?I wish it will return the /sdcard, but actually the value is /storage/sdcard.
SDPATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to find whether those two directories are actually point to the same space. Right?

Assume they are, then it is very possible to see different permissions, because symbolic link does not inherit permission. It is normally 777 as modified by the umask setting.